# How to Install Minimal Windows 10 TO a Flash Drive

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

Is there a free method to strip down all the unnecessary Windows 10 features before installation and to end up with a very lean ISO file, and then proceed to install said ISO on a USB Flash Drive?

Comment: Is the problem installing windows on a flash drive, or on any drive with limited space?

Comment: Well the problem is, my current HDD is acting up, the red light remains on for long periods of time as if it's trying to do something. And as soon as I physically hit the hard drive, it kind of fixes the problem. And I don't have access to anything, no spare SATA cable or a HDD for that matter. The only thing I have access to, is an 8GB USB flash drive. So I'm thinking maybe I can make a very small Windows 10 ISO file and then install it on the flash drive itself and run Windows from that flash drive however slow the user experience might be.

Comment: You can't install any version of Windows to a flash drive. Your hard drive is dying, you need to get another one. If you act soon, you may be able to clone it to a new drive. If not, you'll have to do a full re-install. There are versions of Linux that will run from a flash drive, such as [Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/#:~:text=Provide%20your%20downloaded%20Ubuntu%20ISO,storage%20on%20the%20USB%20drive.)

Comment: Oh but you actually can. There's a feature in Windows called Windows To Go that does exactly that. Also Rufus has the same feature as well. So the question then becomes how small the Windows ISO can actually become, and by what software?

Comment: You might want to update the title of the question then!

Comment: Could you please suggest a better title? I appreciate it.

Comment: @wemepe - Windows to Go is only available in pre- Windows 10 Enterprise and Education versions. Windows To Go is removed in Windows 10, version 2004 and later. It also requires a specific type of USB that is no longer supported by many OEMs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dism` in cmd/powershell to mount the installation iso file (more info in this [official microsoft post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/mount-and-modify-a-windows-image-using-dism)). Then, you can disable some features through dism, or you can manually delete the files in the mounted folder and then proceed to save the image. Lots of things can go wrong if you decide to delete folders and files yourself.

A program that I use is [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/) - you can make a lightweight image with the free version, with basically no restrictions. Paid version has some extra stuff included. It lets you choose which features to delete from the image.

You can of course find lots of minimal images from other people on various places on the internet. Only install those if you trust the makers of the iso files.